# setting JNDI configurations without xml

Tags: jndi

Can anyone please post a link of tutorial for setting JNDI configurations without xml files for MySQL???I don't want configurations in xml files. But instead I want to use in Java files?

Comment: You can set some things in `/jndi.properties`, but first it would be best for you to explain your aversion to XML.

Comment: Actually for the project on which I am working, there is client's requirement that he want front end and back end separate , separate both. so for this I have to configure database connections in back end side.